# Сравнение массива и объекта

Tags: javascript

Нужно сравнить массив с необходимыми полями с ключами объекта, если совпадают true, иначе false.

```js
const requiredFields = [ 'title', 'price', 'discount' ];


let form1 = {
  title: 'Товар Телепорт бытовой VZHIH-101',
  price: 7800,
  discount: 0
};

let form2 = {
  title: 'Товар Телепорт бытовой VZHIH-101',
  discount: 10
}
if ( isValidPosition(form1, requiredFields) ) {
  console.log('Форма №1 заполнена верно');
} else {
    console.log('В форме №1 не заполнены необходимые поля');
}
if ( isValidPosition(form2, requiredFields) ) {
  console.log('Форма №2 заполнена верно');
} else {
  console.log('В форме №2 не заполнены необходимые поля');
}

function isValidPosition(form, settings) {
  let formKeys = Object.keys(form);
  console.log(formKeys);
  for (let i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
    if (settings.indexOf(formKeys[i]) === -1) {
      console.log('Форма заполнена не верно');
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('Форма заполнена верно');
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: В чем вопрос, собственно?

Comment: Если в объекте 3 ключа таких же как в массиве то true, если нет то false

Comment: `return true;` вынеси из цикла, else можно убрать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через фильтр выделить все элементы, которых нет в объекте и если таких элементов нет, то выводить `true`.

```js
// Функция проверки
var isValid = function(obj, arr__properties) {
  var arr__gap = arr__properties.filter(property => obj[property] === undefined);

  return arr__gap.length === 0;
};

// Данные
var requiredFields = ['title', 'price', 'discount'];

var form1 = {
  title: 'Товар Телепорт бытовой VZHIH-101',
  price: 7800,
  discount: 0
};
var form2 = {
  title: 'Товар Телепорт бытовой VZHIH-101',
  discount: 10
}

// Проверка
if (isValid(form1, requiredFields)) {
  console.log('Форма №1 заполнена верно');
} else {
  console.log('В форме №1 не заполнены необходимые поля');
}
if (isValid(form2, requiredFields)) {
  console.log('Форма №2 заполнена верно');
} else {
  console.log('В форме №2 не заполнены необходимые поля');
}
```

**UPDATA:**

По подсказке пользователя [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) можно сделать более краткую проверку с помощью функции [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
// Функция проверки
var isValid = function(obj, arr__properties) {
  return arr__properties.every(property => obj[property] !== undefined);
};

// Данные
var requiredFields = ['title', 'price', 'discount'];

var form1 = {
  title: 'Товар Телепорт бытовой VZHIH-101',
  price: 7800,
  discount: 0
};
var form2 = {
  title: 'Товар Телепорт бытовой VZHIH-101',
  discount: 10
}

// Проверка
if (isValid(form1, requiredFields)) {
  console.log('Форма №1 заполнена верно');
} else {
  console.log('В форме №1 не заполнены необходимые поля');
}
if (isValid(form2, requiredFields)) {
  console.log('Форма №2 заполнена верно');
} else {
  console.log('В форме №2 не заполнены необходимые поля');
}
```

Comment: если использовать [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) локальная переменная не нужна

Comment: @Grundy, благодарю. Добавил вариант с функцией `every`